# Flutter gradle Build failed with an exception. > Could not find com.otaliastudios:transcoder:0.9.1

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

Hi when i try to run my app on android emulator i get the following error,

iam using video_compress 3.1.2 dependency for my project ,

It works on ios emulator but gradle gives this error i couldn't figure it out

i found this link on maven repositories but I couldn't find how to use it

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.otaliastudios:transcoder:0.9.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1/transcoder-0.9.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1/transcoder-0.9.1.pom
       - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1/transcoder-0.9.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :video_compress

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 20s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited
```

---Gradle kotlin----
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.otaliastudios/transcoder
implementation("com.otaliastudios:transcoder:0.9.1")

I put this dependency in the build.gradle file under the android -> app, but I couldn't run it.

like this--

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')
    implementation("com.otaliastudios:transcoder:0.9.1") //------------------------>new added
}
```

Answer (score 17):

I was having the same error, and as it states the problem seems to be that that specific version of the transcoder lib is not available on maven or google repos.

With a rapid google search I found [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1) webpage which shows that it's available on the jcenter repository. So, just by adding `jcenter()` to the android/build.gradle file I was able to solve the issue. It should be looks similar to this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: indeed it helped. Is the issue that this package is not using up to date repository?

Answer (score 6):

Use version 3.1.1. Remember to remove the ^ in your dependency line.

```
video_compress: 3.1.1
```

https://github.com/jonataslaw/VideoCompress/issues/207#issuecomment-1327373676

Answer (score 0):

Add this one in `app/build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
.../
implementation 'com.otaliastudios:transcoder:0.10.5'
}
```